# Google calendar backup does not save event creation date

Tags: google-calendar-api

Is there a way to backup a Google calendar and then import it while saving the creation dates of events? This is critical for me to calculate when appointments were created (weekly billing cycle), as opposed to when they are scheduled for (perhaps months down the road).

I've tested it, and when you import and exported calendar, it marks all events as created on the date they were imported on, not when they were actually created, which is ludicrous.

Does anyone know a work around to save the getCreated date?
Thanks a bunch, Bob

Answer (score 0):

You can open the .ICS file of the exported calendar and check the event creation date and time. Every event starts with a BEGIN and ends with an END tag as below:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20160404T143000Z
DTEND:20160404T150000Z
DTSTAMP:20160405T230139Z
UID:i0juj2f62qeth85ip6qucbul8g@google.com
CREATED:20160404T103834Z
DESCRIPTION:
LAST-MODIFIED:20160404T103843Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY: Meet Richard in the office
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
```

Hope that helps.. Use Notepad++, works well

Also check this https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9043/how-can-i-find-out-when-i-added-an-event-to-my-google-calendar

Comment: Yes thank you, I am aware of this, but that wasn't my question. I am wondering why when I import that data, the calendar uses today's date as the creation date for every event imported. I've created a php program using the Google Calendar API, and I need to have the creation date correct in the calendar itself which I access by "$dateCreated = new DateTime($event->getCreated());"